# query involving xpath does not return any rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, oracle

I have a table with xmltype I need to be able to query against using XPath. When I include a where clause condition involving Xpath Rails does not return any rows. when I copy the generated query from Rails the log and execute it standalone it does return the expected rows.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table tab WHERE ( tab.myxml.existsnode('//MyNode')  = 1
```

Code:

```
select("tab.myxml.getclobval() myxml").
from("my_table tab").
where("tab.myxml.existsnode(:xp) = 1", :xp=>"//MyNode")
```

Answer (score 1):

No idea why, but it works when I specify "!=0" instead of "=1" in existsnode:

```
select("tab.myxml.getclobval() myxml").
from("my_table tab").
where("tab.myxml.existsnode(:xp) != 0", :xp=>"//MyNode")
```

Comment: That's weird.  Maybe you should query V$SQL to see exactly what statement is getting submitted to the database.  Also, you may want to consider using XMLEXISTS instead of EXISTSNODE ([which is deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions057.htm#i1006711)).

Comment: Thanks, xmlexists works fine. Was not aware existsnodewas deprecated.